# How to convert a nested array with parent child relationship to a plain array?

Tags: javascript, arrays, algorithm, tree, depth-first-search

I have an array with nested objects having parent-child relationship like so:

```
[
{id: 1, title: 'hello', parent: 0, children: [
    {id: 3, title: 'hello', parent: 1, children: [
        {id: 4, title: 'hello', parent: 3, children: [
            {id: 5, title: 'hello', parent: 4, children: []},
            {id: 6, title: 'hello', parent: 4, children: []}
        ]},
        {id: 7, title: 'hello', parent: 3, children: []}
    ]}
]},
{id: 2, title: 'hello', parent: 0, children: [
    {id: 8, title: 'hello', parent: 2, children: []}
]}
]
```

I need to convert it into a plain array retaining the parent child relationship like so and in the order of parent and all its children returned first before proceeding on to the next parent.

```
[
{id: 1, title: 'hello', parent: 0},
{id: 3, title: 'hello', parent: 1},
{id: 4, title: 'hello', parent: 3},
{id: 5, title: 'hello', parent: 4},
{id: 6, title: 'hello', parent: 4},
{id: 7, title: 'hello', parent: 3},
{id: 2, title: 'hello', parent: 0},
{id: 8, title: 'hello', parent: 2}
]
```

I was able to convert the other way round with a recursive function.

But I need to do the opposite in an efficient way. There is multilevel nesting as shown in the sample nested array.

EDIT: Updated the nested array to have an empty children array for leaf nodes.

And also, an answer in ES5 would help.

Comment: @a.mola: see answer of *mplungjan* for a non recursive solution.

Comment: Your question is tagged with `breadth-first-search` but your flat array is an output from a depth-first-search.

Comment: @trincot You're right. Changed the tag.

Answer (score 3):

I just use a simple recursive function to make an array object into a plain array

```js
var arr = [ {id: 1, title: 'hello', parent: 0, children: [ {id: 3, title: 'hello', parent: 1, children: [ {id: 4, title: 'hello', parent: 3, children: [ {id: 5, title: 'hello', parent: 4, children: []}, {id: 6, title: 'hello', parent: 4, children: []} ]}, {id: 7, title: 'hello', parent: 3, children: []} ]} ]}, {id: 2, title: 'hello', parent: 0, children: [ {id: 8, title: 'hello', parent: 2, children: []} ]} ];

var result = [];
var convertArrToObj = (arr) => {
  arr.forEach(e => {
    if (e.children) {
      result.push({
        id: e.id,
        title: e.title,
        parent: e.parent
      });
      convertArrToObj(e.children);
    } else result.push(e);

  });
};
convertArrToObj(arr);
console.log(result);
```

Comment: Nice and simple.

Comment: Thanks. I updated this solution a bit by deep cloning 'e' object and deleting children property from it. This is just in case I have a lot of properties, it'd be better to just remove the one children property. 


`var i= JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(e)); delete i.subTrendingTopics; result.push(i);`

Answer (score 3):

In ES5 you can also use some *functional programming* approach, and flatten an array with `[].concat.apply`:

```js
function flatten(arr) {
    return [].concat.apply([], arr.map(function (obj) {
        return [].concat.apply([
            { id: obj.id, title: obj.title, parent: obj.parent }
        ], flatten(obj.children));
    }));
}

let arr = [{id: 1, title: 'hello', parent: 0, children: [{id: 3, title: 'hello', parent: 1, children: [{id: 4, title: 'hello', parent: 3, children: [{id: 5, title: 'hello', parent: 4, children: []},{id: 6, title: 'hello', parent: 4, children: []}]},{id: 7, title: 'hello', parent: 3, children: []}]}]},{id: 2, title: 'hello', parent: 0, children: [{id: 8, title: 'hello', parent: 2, children: []}]}];

console.log(flatten(arr));
```

In ES6 the same algorithm reduces to the following:

```js
const flatten = arr => arr.flatMap(({children, ...o}) => [o, ...flatten(children)]);

let arr = [{id: 1, title: 'hello', parent: 0, children: [{id: 3, title: 'hello', parent: 1, children: [{id: 4, title: 'hello', parent: 3, children: [{id: 5, title: 'hello', parent: 4, children: []},{id: 6, title: 'hello', parent: 4, children: []}]},{id: 7, title: 'hello', parent: 3, children: []}]}]},{id: 2, title: 'hello', parent: 0, children: [{id: 8, title: 'hello', parent: 2, children: []}]}];

console.log(flatten(arr));
```

Answer (score 2):

Using ES5 would require a lot more lines of code and like you said is not very efficient.

Here's my ES5 version, you should be able to notice the difference in performance

```js
const data = [{id:1,title:'hello',parent:0,children:[{id:3,title:'hello',parent:1,children:[{id:4,title:'hello',parent:3,children:[{id:5,title:'hello',parent:4,children:[]},{id:6,title:'hello',parent:4,children:[]}]},{id:7,title:'hello',parent:3,children:[]}]}]},{id:2,title:'hello',parent:0,children:[{id:8,title:'hello',parent:2,children:[]}]}];

// Recursively
function reduceArrayDimension(array) {
  var level = [];

  array.forEach(function(item) {
    level.push({
      id: item.id,
      title: item.title,
      parent: item.parent
    });
    item.children.forEach(function(child) {
        reduceArrayDimension([child]).forEach(function(childItem) {
          level.push(childItem);
        });
    });
  });

  return level;
}

console.log(reduceArrayDimension(data));
```

And ES6

```js
const data=[{id:1,title:'hello',parent:0,children:[{id:3,title:'hello',parent:1,children:[{id:4,title:'hello',parent:3,children:[{id:5,title:'hello',parent:4,children:[]},{id:6,title:'hello',parent:4,children:[]}]},{id:7,title:'hello',parent:3,children:[]}]}]},{id:2,title:'hello',parent:0,children:[{id:8,title:'hello',parent:2,children:[]}]}];

// Recursively
function reduceArrayDimension(array) {
  const level = [];
  
  array.forEach(item => {
    level.push({id: item.id, title: item.title, parent: item.parent});
    if (item.children) level.push(...reduceArrayDimension(item.children));
  });
  
  return level;
}

console.log(reduceArrayDimension(data));
```

Comment: This generates an order from child to parent. I needed parent to child. I think your previous solution gave the right output afaik. Anyway, thanks for the effort.

Comment: @PriyankerRao I’ve edited it now for Parent to Child

Answer (score 0):

If the data is not very large, this could be a pragmatic method

```js
const data = [{ id: 1, title: 'hello', parent: 0, children: [{ id: 3, title: 'hello', parent: 1, children: [{ id: 4, title: 'hello', parent: 3, children: [{ id: 5, title: 'hello', parent: 4 }, { id: 6, title: 'hello', parent: 4 , children:[]} ] }, { id: 7, title: 'hello', parent: 3 } ] }] }, { id: 2, title: 'hello', parent: 0, children: [{ id: 8, title: 'hello', parent: 2 }] } ];

const str = JSON.stringify(data)
  .replaceAll('"children":[',"},")
  .replaceAll("]}","")
  .replaceAll(",,",",")   // handle empty children
  .replaceAll(",}","}");


console.log(JSON.parse(str).sort((a,b) => a.id-b.id))
```

Comment: Updated the question to include an empty empty array for leaf nodes. This throws an error for the updated scenario. I could parse the object and delete an empty child array to make it work though.

Comment: @PriyankerRao The update handles empty children

Comment: I would never want to count on something like this, but I'm impressed that it works!

Answer (score 0):

if data is large can consider use tail optimization and async/await

```js
const arr = [
{id: 1, title: 'hello', parent: 0, children: [
    {id: 3, title: 'hello', parent: 1, children: [
        {id: 4, title: 'hello', parent: 3, children: [
            {id: 5, title: 'hello', parent: 4},
            {id: 6, title: 'hello', parent: 4}
        ]},
        {id: 7, title: 'hello', parent: 3}
    ]}
]},
{id: 2, title: 'hello', parent: 0, children: [
    {id: 8, title: 'hello', parent: 2}
]}
];

const convertArr = (arr) => {
  return arr.reduce((init, cur) => {
    const plain = init.concat(cur);
    const children = cur.children;
    return plain.concat(children && children.length ? convertArr(children) : [])
  }, [])
}

const generateArr = (arr) => {
  return convertArr(arr).map(v => ({
    id: v.id,
    parent: v.parent,
    title: v.title
  }))
}
console.log('result:', generateArr(arr))
```

Comment: Far too complex

Answer (score 0):

You can use a generator function:

```js
var arr = [ {id: 1, title: 'hello', parent: 0, children: [ {id: 3, title: 'hello', parent: 1, children: [ {id: 4, title: 'hello', parent: 3, children: [ {id: 5, title: 'hello', parent: 4, children: []}, {id: 6, title: 'hello', parent: 4, children: []} ]}, {id: 7, title: 'hello', parent: 3, children: []} ]} ]}, {id: 2, title: 'hello', parent: 0, children: [ {id: 8, title: 'hello', parent: 2, children: []} ]} ];
function* flatten(d){
   for (var i of d){
      yield {id:i.id, title:i.title, parent:i.parent}
      yield* flatten(i.children)
   }
}
console.log([...flatten(arr)])
```